# buildx build --platform amd64,arm64 --push creates 3 resources in ECR - 2 images and 1 image index, how do I tag them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, build, amazon-ecr, multiarch

Running this command -
`docker buildx build --platforms linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t mytag --push .`

It creates an image index and 2 images in my ECR.

1. How do I tag the images and the image index in one command? For now I can only tag the image index.
2. How can I know for sure that each image is different arch and the image index contains both images?
3. If I pull the image index from amd64 or arm64 laptop, would he know to pull the right image for my arch? how? I wanted to have multi arch image, is it the image index?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68790184/596285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How do I tag the images and the image index in one command? For now I can only tag the image index.

There are a variety of tools out there for this. The ones I frequently recommend are Google's crane, RedHat's skopeo, and my own regclient. E.g. with regclient/regctl:

```
regctl image copy $image@$(regctl image digest $image:$tag --platform linux/amd64) $image:${tag}-amd64
regctl image copy $image@$(regctl image digest $image:$tag --platform linux/arm64) $image:${tag}-arm64
```

> 2. How can I know for sure that each image is different arch and the image index contains both images?

You can inspect the manifest, docker now has this built-in:

```bash
docker buildx imagetools inspect $image:$tag
```

Or with various other tools:

```bash
regctl manifest get $image:$tag
crane manifest $image:$tag
```

> 3. If I pull the image index from amd64 or arm64 laptop, would he know to pull the right image for my arch? how? I wanted to have multi arch image, is it the image index?

Yes, the image index is how a registry stores a multi-platform image. It contains an array of descriptors to each other other manifests and their platform. The container runtimes (like docker) know how to pick their local platform from that list. E.g. here's what the busybox multi-platform manifest looks like:

```
$ regctl manifest get busybox --format '{{jsonPretty . }}'
{
  "manifests": [
    {
      "digest": "sha256:51de9138b0cc394c813df84f334d638499333cac22edd05d0300b2c9a2dc80dd",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "amd64",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:40b22bd39e49b9cea975a391de1caad93d63fadc3d23b7dcbf96ec6656064737",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v5"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:d88e0acf1f43052d87d2acb55823f1074a7fd0f7abfe23c07d00e1616cdd15e0",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v6"
      },
      "size": 527
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:51a9e8ef37a92df3f231b6f96b86c45a622a9078a642b82aa2f45e96c850d92a",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v7"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:9421d4cc473b282bf48888476604444fa3c74f6e3f5cddfa210e773c534cd33d",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm64",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v8"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:da6b2a01ddb011c518d5b07245d781de7c33d6e4cb058d137e9c06ffce4ad7f3",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "386",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:5fa4e832d41ced43f8a01216c3d6af2ee1607b697cea7c1171d8eb8e2a951388",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "mips64le",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:b6b4d55059e0cabc8ed615b2a656303f060e16a24b28cb2c18f71e896795e509",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "ppc64le",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:92f6eed1de620dd42e1fb36e4a04e394d462b180cb48672189a90cb236df35f7",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "riscv64",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 527
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:a748a1de3d1647c5f4c42c4ccc3d55024a40d9663e3d7d1287e319c342df4d9a",
      "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "s390x",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 528
    }
  ],
  "mediaType": "application\/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
  "schemaVersion": 2
}
```

From the comments:

> why does the image index and the other 2 images are all the same size? shouldn't the image index be much much smaller since it contains only the metadata?

The size in the manifest list is the size of each of the nested manifests, which is also just JSON. You need to look at the size of the filesystem layers within those image manifests to see each image size:

```
$ regctl manifest get busybox@sha256:51de9138b0cc394c813df84f334d638499333cac22edd05d0300b2c9a2dc80dd --format '{{jsonPretty . }}'
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": 1457,
    "digest": "sha256:827365c7baf137228e94bcfc6c47938b4ffde26c68c32bf3d3a7762cd04056a5"
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 2587828,
      "digest": "sha256:2123501b93d459033750d3ea725953060ed9bb83bac7c13e46c675be22b69f4a"
    }
  ]
}

$ regctl manifest get busybox@sha256:40b22bd39e49b9cea975a391de1caad93d63fadc3d23b7dcbf96ec6656064737 --format '{{jsonPretty . }}'
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": 1470,
    "digest": "sha256:9c8ab461a9c7a50fbb07e348ab2d47386fd201b7898fe7308fd9c657567bbbd8"
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 1931376,
      "digest": "sha256:1ddd1b6487ad850ff46f8fb4859302299e7799c47ba4cd9da3c9b27ad96e50a3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: why does the image index and the other 2 images are all the same size? shouldn't the image index be much much smaller since it contains only the metadata?

Comment: The size listed on each descriptor in the index is the size of the referenced image manifest. When you pull the specific digest, you will receive that number of bytes of JSON. That image manifest JSON has its own references to the image config and filesystem layers, each with their own size.

Comment: So thats the real sizes for 2 platforms amd64 and arm64?
This is what I see in ECR -

Image Index = (Size 666.97, its just represent a reference to the size, its not an actual size since its a metadata)
Image AMD64 - (Size 666.95)
Image ARM64  (Size 666.97)

Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @EilonA I can't say for sure what an ECR UI is showing, but the size in any descriptor is an exact number of bytes, so it won't have a decimal. To understand the difference between the manifest size and layer size, see the OCI spec: https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/spec.md

Comment: Why does building the image using buildx takes much longer? is it because the node its building on is using amd64 and it tries building arm64 with an emulator?
If so, whats the easiest way to increase the speed of the build to be the same as single platform?

Comment: Please use comments for clarifying answers to the original question. Use the "Ask Question" button to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I tag the images and the image index in one command? For now I can only tag the image index.

The `buildx` command does not provide this functionality. The intended behavior is that the individual images for each architecture are untagged. You can, however, tag the images yourself using the ECR APIs (i.e., [`put-image`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/put-image.html)) or by pulling the image by digest tagging/pushing new tags (i.e., `docker pull` then `docker tag`, then `docker push`).

> How can I know for sure that each image is different arch and the image index contains both images?
> If I pull the image index from amd64 or arm64 laptop, would he know to pull the right image for my arch? how? I wanted to have multi arch image, is it the image index?

You can view the image manifest (which can be retrieved with [`batch-get-image`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/batch-get-image.html)), which will specify each image, its digest, and architecture information.

```
aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name my/repo --image-ids imageTag=mytag --query 'images[].imageManifest' --output text
```

You can use this information to verify an image you pull.

You can also use `docker image inspect` to view the architecture of an image you pulled:

```
docker pull my/repo:mytag
docker image inspect my/repo:mytag
```

In the response JSON body, there is a key `"Architecture"` that specifies the architecture.

It's also worth mentioning that the docker client will automatically pull the appropriate architecture according to the daemon host's architecture. For example, you can use the same command like `docker pull postgres` on an AMD64 machine and ARM machine and the appropriate image will be pulled according to the system architecture.

Comment: why does the image index and the other 2 images are all the same size? shouldn't the image index be much much smaller since it contains only the metadata?

Comment: facing the same issue, in which it's showing image size 0 for pushed images using buildx